# Append to svg group on drag drop

Tags: jquery-ui, d3.js

I want to append a circle to group on drop. I tried with jquery ui draggable and droppable approach but I am unable to drag the circle when I use when jquery function. Any other alternative for this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xLkx08z1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 800)
                        .attr("height", 803);

                var circle3 = svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("id", "tobeDrooped").attr("cx", 35).attr("cy", 310).attr("r", 25)
                        .style("fill", "white").style('cursor', 'move').style("stroke", "black");

                var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function () {
                            var g = this;
                            return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                                y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
                        })
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            g = this;
                            translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                            x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                                    y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                            d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                var group = svgContainer.append("g")
                        .attr("id", "mygroup")
                        .call(dragGroup)
                        .style('cursor', 'move')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");
                group.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 250).attr("y", 250)
                        .attr("width", 151).attr("height", 141)
                        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
                        .style("fill", "white");

                var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function ()
                        {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy")};
                        })

                        .on('dragend', function (d) {
                            var mouseCoordinates = d3.mouse(this);
                            if (mouseCoordinates[0] > 170) {
                                //Append new element
                                var circle2 = d3.select("svg").append("circle")
                                        .classed("drg", true)
                                        .attr("cx", 100)
                                        .attr("cy", 100)
                                        .attr("r", 20)
                                        .attr("cx", mouseCoordinates[0])
                                        .attr("cy", mouseCoordinates[1])
                                        .style("fill", "white")
                                        .style("stroke", "black");
                            }
                        });
                circle3.call(drag);


        // JQUERY FUNCTION
                $(function () {
                    $("#tobeDrooped").draggable();
                    $("#mygroup").droppable({
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            group.append("circle")
                                    .style("stroke", "green")
                                    .style("fill", "grey")
                                    .attr("r", 40)
                                    .attr("cx", 100)
                                    .attr("cy", 100);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of jquery droppable function from other site: http://jsfiddle.net/sb6ja2ru/

Comment: so you want to drop the rectangle and it should become a circle as shown in your demo. Then that circle should also be draggable? is it a compulsion to do it with jquery draggable can I use d3 draggable..

Comment: I want to drag the circle in to the rectangle(svg group) and then circle should be part of group and later if I want, circle should be removed when I drag it out of the rectangle

Comment: It doesn't have to be jquery. I just tried with it

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/jdfhfzhj/) a simple Fiddle showcasing `d3.behaviour.drag` ([more info](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#origin)). If you drag off of the red circle it will generate a new circle. If you drag any of these new circles, it will instead change the location of that circle. You'll have to deal with appending to the group yourself, but it shouldn't be hard to use the `getBBox()` function to determine if the `dragend` triggers within the bounds of a `g` element, and if so then `append` the circle to that group.

Comment: More on the `getBBox()` function, you'd have to use `d3.selectAll("g")` then act on that array with `.each(function (d) { var tmpArr = d3.select(d).selectAll("*") })` and run through this resulting array, generating `minX, minY, maxX, maxY` values and then checking if `d3.event.x, d3.event.y` is within those bounds (on `dragend`). If yes, `d3.select(d).append(targetCircle);`, or something of this sort.

Comment: You are right. Adding more circles are placed at different location on drag. Here's the preview of that: http://jsbin.com/gigejeniso/1/edit?html,output   I  am new d3, I don't really know much advanced stuff yet. I tried with bounding box example you have provided but don't know how to use `.each(function)` and minX maxY etc

Comment: any example to check the `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` is within bounds of group on drag end. please help.

Comment: potatopeelings just posted an answer, but I'll still provide an alternate approach. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/jdfhfzhj/2/) the Fiddle. Slightly different than my original suggestion, it selects all the elements on the page, checks if they are a member of a group, and if so it then checks the `getBBox()` against the drag position, and if it is within that element then it inherits the styling of that element. Where it says `your code here` is where you'd make it add the `targetCircle` to `this.parentNode`.

Comment: @JSBob - you might want to post that as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: @JSBob Thanks for the fiddle. I was analyzing the code whole day with console logs and alert to understand it better.  I tried appending a circle to target group but its not appending. Please check if I am doing it correctly? Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wutz65bq/

Comment: @JSBob Here's the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fceauoub/   How do I prevent circle cloning inside of group? The circle inside should be draggable but not clonable

Comment: @JSBob `". If you drag off of the red circle it will generate a new circle. If you drag any of these new circles, it will instead change the location of that circle. "` How did you figure out that it will change the location of circle? I am trying to understand this so I can fix my issue

Comment: @kittu The way I did it in that Fiddle was to class the red circle with `baseCircle`. You could do the same thing by adding an `id` to it, the purpose is to allow the program to differentiate it. When `dragstart` is called, it checks if the target object has the `baseCircle` class (`if (d3.select(this).classed("baseCircle") == true)`), and if it does it will append a new circle and then sets that as the object that is moved by the drag event. Otherwise, it just sets the current target as the item to be moved (`targetCircle`).

Comment: @JSBob Thanks for the reply. A lot has changed in my code from our previous conversation. Now the challenge is I am not able to move the circle element which is inside the group element. How do I fix this? so I can add/remove elements from the group?

Comment: @kittu That could get a bit tricky. You'll have to define what exactly determines a group: is it a rectangle? My suggestion would be to apply `.classed("someClass", true)` to objects that you want to be moveable after being added to the group. Then on your drag event you can check if the object has that class, and if it does then only move that object rather than the whole group. If you want to get more complex you could allow them to select an object on click, and if an object is clicked and then dragged it will move the object, otherwise it will move the group.

Comment: @JSBob Yes rectangle will be the group and the circles I am adding have a class called "circleAdded". So inside `drag` event or `dragstart` event I have to check if the circle class is present?

Comment: @kittu Exactly. It'd probably be better to put it inside the `drag` event, but that is the idea. If it has the class then modify `cx, cy`. If not, then modify the `translate` of the `g` element (`this.parentNode`).

Answer (score 1):

This changes the rectangle to red (you can do anything else you want like moving the circle to the centre of the rectangle, disabling the drag behaviour, etc.) once the circle is dragged inside it (it checks if the circle centre crosses the boundaries).

```
window.onload = function () {
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 803);

    var rectg = svgContainer.append("g")
    var rect = rectg
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 250).attr("y", 250)
        .attr("width", 151).attr("height", 141)
        .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
        .style("fill", "white");

    var circle3 = svgContainer.append("circle")
            .attr("id", "tobeDrooped").attr("cx", 35).attr("cy", 310).attr("r", 25)
            .style("fill", "white").style('cursor', 'move').style("stroke", "black");

    var drag =
        d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("dragstart", function (d, i) {
                this.setAttribute("dx", event.x)
                this.setAttribute("dy", event.y)
            })
            .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                var cx = Number(this.getAttribute("cx")) + event.x - Number(this.getAttribute("dx"));
                var cy = Number(this.getAttribute("cy")) + event.y - Number(this.getAttribute("dy"));
                this.setAttribute("dx", event.x)
                this.setAttribute("dy", event.y)
                this.setAttribute("cx", cx)
                this.setAttribute("cy", cy)

                if (cx > Number(rect.attr("x")) && cx < (Number(rect.attr("x")) + Number(rect.attr("width"))) &&
                    cy > Number(rect.attr("y")) && cy < (Number(rect.attr("y")) + Number(rect.attr("height")))) {
                    rectg.node().appendChild(this);
                    rect.style("fill", "red");
                }
            })
            .on("dragend", function (d, i) {
                this.removeAttribute("dx")
                this.removeAttribute("dy")
            })

    circle3.call(drag);
};
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/6vojozy1/

Comment: I forgot to mention that draggable element should be a clone of original element. Sorry my bad. Anyway I upvoted the answer. Even though I am new to d3, your answer seems readable and a bit easy to understand. is it possible to clone the element on drag and then drop into svg group?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There's one small issue. After running the program and checking the elements in console, I can see on each drag of circle, it is adding a circle to the group leading to multiple addition of circles to the group though it is not visible on the screen and this might lead to performance problem I guess

Comment: Sorry! Kind of missed this comment. I assume you got this sorted out pretty neatly - saw your other question :-)